# How to remove .vue extension from imports when using TypeScript in Vue.JS?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tsconfig

I created a project with vue-cli3 and included TypeScript

My **src/app.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <hello-world msg="test"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld';

@Component({
  components: { HelloWorld },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>
```

the compiler throwing an error in "Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld'";

The component HelloWorld exists.

However, if I remove the `lang="ts"` or add the `.vue` extension then everything compiles fine. In my **tsconfig.json**, i have

```
  "paths": {
    "@/*": [ "src/*" ]
  },
```

Is it an issue with `tsconfig.json` or something else?

Answer (score 3):

In your sources root folder you probably have a file named `shims-vue.d.ts` with contents like these:

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

What this file does is tell the Typescript compiler that all files ending in `.vue` have the `Vue` type. Otherwise, those files have no type and Typescript cannot work with them.

This is why you *need* the `.vue` extension: if you remove it, Typescript doesn't know the type of the file and can't compile. So, in short, the answer is that **you can't** remove the extension.

*More advanced answer*:

Theoretically, you *can* remove the extension, but you would need to declare the module shim with a different expression. For example, you could tell Typescript that all the files in a folder have the Vue type. This is, however, way worse than just shimming the `.vue` extension, which is the recommended default.

Answer (score 0):

True to add `.vue` at the end of every vuejs component when is imported.

```
`import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld';
```

should be:

```
 import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

Comment: the question asks "how to remove .vue extension"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `awesome-typescript-loader` package, then you can import without `.vue` extension. If you are using SCF component like you do, insure you have `vue-loader` package installed and `shims-vue.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the WebStorm (JetBrains) IDE then you could automatically add ".vue" extension when add a new component:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48458?_ga=2.239486406.49000252.1666525745-1067897246.1664897407&_gac=1.84026987.1664897412.CjwKCAjws--ZBhAXEiwAv-RNL4Iv2BkQbCojuXeQctoNjErtdI_0HKHBXYuL0abKd6rnQEbjIQTScxoCfSkQAvD_BwE&_gl=1*mrrnth*_ga*MTA2Nzg5NzI0Ni4xNjY0ODk3NDA3*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY2NjUzMDE5OS42LjEuMTY2NjUzMDMzNS4wLjAuMA..

Answer (score -1):

This line `import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld';` shoud be `import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue`.

Because the compiler think the `@/components/HelloWorld` is a `.ts` or `.js` file, but it didn't exist.

Comment: i said the same thing in my question. that's why i'm asking "how to remove .vue extension"

Comment: I was looking into the same issue a while ago; the only answer I found in multiple places is: you cannot. Keep the '.vue' extension. Not a big deal anyway

Answer (score -1):

It's already an old question but it seems that you need to add the shim-vue.d.ts

```
//shims-vue.d.ts

declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}
```

Can find more here : [What does the shims-tsx.d.ts file do in a Vue-Typescript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622621/what-does-the-shims-tsx-d-ts-file-do-in-a-vue-typescript-project)

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding this code into `shims-vue.d.ts`, if you have only `.vue` files inside your `components` folder

```
declare module '@/components/*' {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```