# TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations. ts-loader-default_0c5a263502dc9404

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack, webpack-5

### Problem

I get the following error from a webpack build using development mode.

```
TS2307: Cannot find module ./App.vue or its corresponding type declarations. 
ts-loader-default_0c5a263502dc9404
```

A would like to achieve a clean webpack build

---

### Current setup

I have a project containing Webpack, Typescript & Vue.

### Project structure

```
dist 
    bundle.js
    index.html
node_modules
src
    App.vue
    index.html
    index.ts
package.json
shims-vue.d.ts
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

### Package.json - let me know if I am missing any packages

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "test": "webpack -c webpack.config.js"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.47",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
        "pinia": "^2.0.34",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
        "typescript": "^5.0.3",
        "vue": "^3.2.47",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.1",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
        "webpack": "^5.78.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.2",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.21"
    }
}
```

### Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "dist",
        clean: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
        stats: "errors-only",
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        client: {
            overlay: {
                errors: true,
                warnings: false,
            },
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // Applies to vue files
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            // Applies to both plain `.js` files
            // AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            // Applies to both plain `.ts` files
            // AND `<script lang="ts">` blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            // Applies to both plain `.css` or `.scss` files
            // AND <script lang="css"> or <script lang="scss"> blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["vue-style-loader", "style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".vue"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html",
            title: "TPW Home Development",
            filename: "index.html",
            scriptLoading: "defer",
        }),
    ],
};
```

### Tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "ES2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types"],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]
        },
        "lib": [ 
            "ES5",
            "ES2015",
            "ESNext",
            "DOM", 
            "ScriptHost",
            "DOM.Iterable"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.vue"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        ".vscode",
        "./**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

### Shims-vue.d.ts

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module "*.vue" {
    import type { DefineComponent } from "vue";
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
    export default component;
}
```

### Index.ts

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

import App from "./App.vue"; // Here is the problem, but cannot fix it

const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();

app.use(pinia);
app.mount("#app");
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>Hello in the div</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "app",
});
</script>
```

### Index.html - the index.html in the dist

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="dist/bundle.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Finally

I have also done some configuration in vscode. I have installed the TypeScript Vue Plugin and Vue Language Features extensions, and enabled takeout mode - as mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode). I have also looked at multiple other posts around this issue, such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895690/ts2307-cannot-find-module-app-vue-or-its-corresponding-type-declarations), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622621/what-does-the-shims-tsx-d-ts-file-do-in-a-vue-typescript-project/59788563#59788563), and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788796/how-can-i-import-a-vue-class-component-with-proper-types)

None of which solved my issue. Now, I have another project that was scaffolded using vue-cli which integrated Webpack, Typescript & Vue just fine. So, I tried to copy everything from there into this test project for Webpack, but Webpack still says no. I am completely stuck now and need a new pair of eyes (or multiple). For references, see my GitHub repos [here](https://github.com/DylanWarrener?tab=repositories). This project is the testing-webpack repo and my other project that worked is the tpw-development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're facing is due to having `./**/*.d.ts` as part of your `exclude` array in `tsconfig.json`. You're essentially telling Typescript to ignore your definition files, so your definition within `Shims-vue.d.ts` is not being imported.

Moving `./**/*.d.ts` to `include` within `tsconfig.json` should fix this for you.

Aside from that, everything else looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it. I also needed to place the shims in the src folder, instead of the root.