# TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, webpack

I want to use typescript + Vue 3 to develop a google chrome extension. In the google chrome extension popup index, the typescript code `index.ts` looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  createApp(App)
    .mount('#app')
})
```

and the `App.vue` looks like:

```
<template lang="pug">
.container
  h1 {{ title }}
  hr
  Options
  hr
  Counter
  hr
  Memos
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Options from './components/Options.vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const title = process.env.APP_NAME
    return {
      title
    }
  },
  components: {
    Options,
  }
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
div.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  hr {
    size: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    color: gray;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
</style>
```

when I run this code, shows error like this:

```
➜  reddwaf-translate-plugin git:(main) ✗ npm run dev

> reddwaf-translate-plugin@1.0.0 dev
> rm -rf src/bundle && webpack --mode development --config src/resource/config/webpack.dev.config.js

assets by path popup/ 1.47 KiB
  asset popup/popup.js 1.27 KiB [emitted] (name: popup/popup) 1 related asset
  asset popup/popup.html 201 bytes [emitted]
asset resource/image/logo.png 7.14 KiB [emitted] [from: src/resource/image/logo.png] [copied]
asset manifest.json 1.22 KiB [emitted] [from: src/manifest.json] [copied]
./src/popup/index.ts 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/popup/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/src/popup/index.ts.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
    at successLoader (/frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
    at Object.loader (/frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)

ERROR in /frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/src/popup/index.ts
./src/popup/index.ts 2:16-27
[tsl] ERROR in /frontend/reddwaf-translate-plugin/src/popup/index.ts(2,17)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
ts-loader-default_0c5a263502dc9404

webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 2 errors in 955 ms
```

this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "reddwaf-translate-plugin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "rm -rf src/bundle && webpack --mode development --config src/resource/config/webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "gulp --cwd . --gulpfile build/gulp-build.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/reddwaf-translate-plugin.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/reddwaf-translate-plugin/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/reddwaf-translate-plugin#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.177",
    "@types/webextension-polyfill": "^0.8.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.29",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

and this is the webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    'popup/popup' : './src/popup/' 
  } ,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    },
  },
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../../bundle') ,
    filename : '[name].js'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      
      {
        test : /\.js$/ ,
        exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      } ,
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins : [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "src/manifest.json", to: "manifest.json" },
        { from: "src/resource/image", to: "resource/image" },
      ],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'popup/popup.html',
      template: 'src/popup/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
      __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
    }),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try placing the following in a `src/shims-vue.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Comment: No idea how it worked, but it worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?   Thank you.

Comment: About this matter, someone already shared a light about it 
here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59788563/1214237

Comment: i am using webstorm, this solution worked, 
but i don't know why, 
thank you

Answer (score 4):

About the previous answer, someone already shared a light about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59788563/1214237).

But I've found also that it was a [specific problem](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48651) in Vue + Typescript projects in VSCode. If you're using Volar that is the [official plugin for Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support) instead Vetur and using typescript in your project, you need also [Typescript Vue Plugin (Volar)](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#ide-support).

Sharing it because that solved my IDE issue. Nothing was wrong with the project, which even with red mark, it was running without any error or warning.

Comment: Is the Typescript Vue Plugin also available for the typescript-language-server on Linux or vim-lsp? A workaround seems to be to define a shim file but that effectively disables linting so that's not really a solution. It just removes the error in the editor.